# Tangent property and rhombus

Tags: geometry

A circle is circumscribed by a parallelogram. prove by using tangent property that the parallelogram is a rhombus.  I tried to prove that the adjacent sides of the parallelogram are equal but I lack idea to apply tangent property

Comment: Can you be more specific as to exactly what the "tangent property" is?

Comment: Tangent property is that the tangents drawn from the external point to the circle are equal , they subtend equal angles at the centre and are equally inclined with the line joining the centre and the external point

Answer (score 1):

you can show that the parellogram is a rhombus if the adjacent sides are equal. this follows from the fact that two tangents from a point are equal.